# How to change a specific textbox in a powerpoint slide master

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I have a powerpoint that uses different Master layouts on the slide Master.  Every time we do an update, a specific textbox on a specifc Master slides needs to be updated.  I would like to do so with a macro.

IE I have a slide master with a Generic Title_Slide and 2 variations under that.  It has a "Generic Bullet_slide" with 10 variations under that.

on the "Generic Bullet_Slide" there is a textbox that contains two lines:
"CONFIG. MGR:  [your name], [your code], [your phone #]"
"FILE NAME: [name of file]"

every time we send the project out, we need to update the fields in [] manually.  If we forget its bad news.

I have seen how to loop through all slides, then all shapes to find text boxes.  Can I find a boxs that specifically has those words in it ("CONFIG. MGR:" and "FILE NAME:") ?

Can I search "layout" slides only?  how do I target anything on the layout slide instead of a normal slide?

thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the object named 'ActivePresentation.Designs(x).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts' to access each custom-layout slide in SlideMaster Designs. (You can have more than 1 design in a presentation.)

Accessing sub-objects in the custom-layout slides is just like dealing with those in the normal slides.

I think you can try the following automation code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'Ignore Upper/Lower case

Sub UpdateCustomLayouts()

    Dim DSN As Design
    Dim CL As CustomLayout
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim mName As String, mCode As String, mPhone As String, fName As String

    'First, change following variables before running this macro
    mName = "Your name"
    mCode = "Your code"
    mPhone = "0123456789"
    fName = ActivePresentation.Name

    'Loop each customlayouts
    For Each DSN In ActivePresentation.Designs
        For Each CL In DSN.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
            For Each shp In CL.Shapes
                If shp.HasTextFrame Then

                    'find and update textboxes
                    With shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                        If .Text Like "CONFIG. MGR:*" Then
                            .Text = "CONFIG. MGR: " & mName & ", " & mCode & ", " & mPhone
                        ElseIf .Text Like "FILE NAME:*" Then
                            .Text = "FILE NAME: " & fName
                        End If
                    End With

                End If
            Next shp
        Next CL
    Next DSN

End Sub
```

As I mentioned, first change variables like 'mName, mCode, mPhone, fName' before running.

Comment: Thanks it worked.   I turned the actual part that updates the text box into a sub function.

And I had to set it to look at the Master slides not just the Custom Layout children using `DSN.SlideMaster.Shapes`

Comment: And I want to post the code I made but I can't figure out how.